# How to send an object to MVC controller using AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an object, I need to send it to my MVC controller;
object:

```
params = {Id: 1, UserAge: 32 }

   // Angular $htttp
   function test() {
        var request = $http.post('/user/updateuser/', params);
        return request;
    }
```

c# - controller

```
  public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int UserAge { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void UpdateUser(User user)
        {

        //user Id and user age is always zero. 

        }
```

UserId and UserAge is always 0 i'm not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: I see a route 'post' of `updateuser/update`, but your controller action is (httpget) `Get(User user)` ??

Comment: Yes, the convention is the controller name is UserController and the route is  /User/UpdateUser... the mvc routing and binding logic depends on conventions to be able to deserialize content into strong typed input parameters on the action method.  To see this in action press F12 and hit the enter key in your browser.  Click on the network tab to see it fly.

Comment: Have you checked the traffic in your console? Does it really send the values?

Comment: yup i have check and it is sending

Comment: Be aware that default request content type for $http` is application/json in request body not form encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [FromBody] attribute before the input parameter:

```
public void UpdateUser([FromBody]User user) {}
```